# Copy single file to all matching files after changing filename pattern in bash

Tags: bash, sed, cp

I have a folder containing a set of `cs*.dat3` files like this:

```
$ find dispersion_upper_deck/ -name cs*.dat3
dispersion_upper_deck/cs600011.dat3
dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/cs652203.dat3
dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/cs652103.dat3
dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/cs652204.dat3
dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/cs652104.dat3
dispersion_upper_deck/Runs654/cs654404.dat3
dispersion_upper_deck/Runs654/cs654403.dat3
```

Now, for each of these files I want to replace them with a corresponding `co*.dat3` file that will be copied from a base file named `co_base_dispersion`. Doing it manually, I could for example do `cp co_dispersion_base dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/co652203.dat3` for each file, but I want something that is more automated. I tried the following:

```
$ for cs_file in $(find dispersion_upper_deck/ -name cs*.dat3); do cp -v co_base_dispersion $(dirname $cs_file)/$(basename $cs_file) | sed "s/cs/co/"; done
`co_base_dispersion' -> `./dispersion_upper_deck/co600011.dat3'
`co_base_dispersion' -> `./dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/co652203.dat3'
`co_base_dispersion' -> `./dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/co652103.dat3'
`co_base_dispersion' -> `./dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/co652204.dat3'
`co_base_dispersion' -> `./dispersion_upper_deck/Runs652/co652104.dat3'
`co_base_dispersion' -> `./dispersion_upper_deck/Runs654/co654404.dat3'
`co_base_dispersion' -> `./dispersion_upper_deck/Runs654/co654403.dat3'
```

Now, the output from `cp -v` looks correct, but nothing happens:

```
find dispersion_upper_deck/ -name co*.dat3
$
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: You use sed to change cs to co after you have already copied the files. So it outputs the changed names even though the names of the files have not been changed. Also whats in the `$cs_file` variable. Also do you just want to make lots of copies of the same file with different names ?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Still, I can't make it work by putting `$()` around the entire destination argument like this either: `for cs_file in $(find dispersion_upper_deck/ -name cs*.dat3); do cp -v co_base_dispersion $($(dirname $cs_file)/$(basename $cs_file) | sed "s/cs/co/"); done`. Why is this not possible either? Do you have any other approaches?

Comment: Are you just copying co_base_dispersion, into files with the same name as the ones you currently have but with co instead of cs, so all the files are identical other than name?

Comment: The `$cs_file` variable is created in the beginning of the for loop. It contains each `cs*.dat3` file in the sub-folder `dispersion_upper_deck` and iterates each of the files. I want to make lots of copies of the `co_base_dispersion` file to all `co*.dat3` destinations in the `$cs_file` variable. Any other approaches could be useful as well, it does not *have* to be a for loop.

Comment: Oh yeah didnt read it properly sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, i havent had time to test it though so just let me know if something goes wrong.

```
for cs_file in $(find dispersion_upper_deck/ -name cs*.dat3); do 
    Filename=$(basename $cs_file | sed "s/cs/co/") 
    cp -v co_base_dispersion $(dirname $cs_file)/$Filename
done
```

or Krøllebølles solution without the `$Filename` variable.

```
for cs_file in $(find dispersion_upper_deck/ -name cs*.dat3); do 
    cp -v co_base_dispersion $(dirname $cs_file)/$(basename $cs_file | sed "s/cs/co/")
done
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. The `sed` part must be inside `$()` in the `dirname` part, else the copying is done before piping it to `sed`. The silly thing about this is that now I have to re-create all my `cs*.dat3` files since I have already copied `co_base_dispersion` to all instances of it. Guess I have to get my parentheses straight. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and this works as well: `for cs_file in $(find dispersion_upper_deck/ -name cs*.dat3); do cp -v co_base_dispersion $(dirname $cs_file)/$(basename $cs_file | sed "s/cs/co/"); done`. It is not strictly needed to store the filename in a variable, just make sure to do it properly :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, should have thought of that, its just habit to put everything in variables in case i use them later ha

Comment: Yeah, variables are nice when doing larger scripts. In this case and similar cases I feel that I just need a one-liner to do the task. Just a matter of habit, though. Whatever works.